# RTSP Stream in GStreamer is Jittery on Android

Tags: gstreamer

I have an h264 file which I am streaming using live555 server. I tried the stream using GStreamer, vlc android client and Android API Player. On Gstreamer the Stream is very jittery. The fps is very low and it jumps from frame to frame. On vlc its a lot better but on the Android API it runs very smooth.

I have switched to GStreamer because I need very low latency and Android API does not allow you to change the initial buffer time. In Gstreamer I think its possible to get very low latency.

I have tested 2 h264 files. One is 1280x768 and other is 1980x1080 but results are similar though in low resolution, its less jittery

For GStreamer I have used the Tutorial-5.

Any help ?